# What occurs when stannous fluoride is combined with baking soda in the oral cavity?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I have googled this question in many forms over many months repeatedly.

For some background, when stannous fluoride is combined with water, it forms precipitates and/or oxidizes, rendering it less effective in the oral cavity.  Crest Pro-Health, as an example, adds a stabilizer, a gluconate, to maintain stability of the stannous fluoride. (If anyone can answer the question of how the gluconate stabilizes the stannous fluoride, that would be great too.)

**My main question:** What is the effect (via the chemical reactions) of combining a sodium bicarbonate/hydrogen peroxide solution with stannous fluoride in the oral cavity?  And how is that effect altered if hydrogen peroxide is not used?

According to me, the high pH of the baking soda neutralizes the acidity of the stannous fluoride, thus nullifying the effects of $\ce{SnF2}$. I also feel that the hydrogen peroxide oxidizes the stannous fluoride - and there may be some precipitates. But I am not sure.

I am asking these questions because I want to determine whether I can use a baking soda/peroxide toothpaste followed by an $\ce{SnF2}$/hexametaphosphate toothpaste.